# Números com inicio zero em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, octal

Estou com um problema confuso, em que envio um numero `000214` por AJAX para um controlador `PHP`, e lá ele chega com resultado `140`.

Dei um simples `console.log(000214);` e o resultado no próprio JS foi `140`.

Como eu poderia passar o `000214` corretamente ao controlador?

Comment: Números com zero a direita são a notação octal, vc pode remover os zeros a direta no javascript e se precisar deles e o número for fixo pode fazer um padding no php.

Comment: Se der mais detalhes, eu posso melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dei uma olhada na página do [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) e eles mencionam assim:

> Never write a number with a leading zero (like 07).
>   Some JavaScript versions interpret numbers as octal if they are written with a leading zero.

O seu número 000214 está sendo interpretado como o octal (base 8) de 214.

Eu tentaria passar como octal e converter o número para a base 10 no servidor ou passar como uma string e converter a string para decimal no servidor.

Existe a função [octdec](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_octdec.asp) em php que converte o número de octal para decimal.

```
octdec("140") //deve retornar o seu número 214 sem os zeros que o precedem
```

Comment: no caso eu precisaria passar mesmo o `000214` do jeito que está porque faz parte de um código composto, e a sua solução de string funcionou, já que não preciso fazer operações com este, sendo enviado como `"000214"` no caso

Answer (score 7):

Se é número, passe 214 (sem os zeros). Números iniciados em 0 usam notação octal e não decimal. 214 escrito em octal equivale a 140 escrito em decimal, então você vê uma coisa que o computador entende ser outra, já que ele segue a regra estrita e não usa a intuição inicial.

Dependendo de onde for usado, é possível indicar que esse número é decimal e aí a interpretação pode ser a esperada. Exemplo na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).